# div background image zoom issue

Tags: html, css

I have a div with background image which contains 3 colors of the same icon

[image: icon]
I shift the icon (background-position: top/center/bottom) according to what page is user viewing: [image: div with icon]

All works fine utill I zoom the page (ctrl + mousewheel) - than the background image seems to shift one pixel up or something, so i can see one-pixel line of the other icon at the bottom of my wrapper div: [image: zoomed]

Screens are from IE but it looks even more broken on iPad...
Any thoughts about what is causing this and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: hmm.. i cant see my added screenshots here :-(

Comment: Added another screen(640x480 bmp), again nothing happened :-/

Comment: We can see your screenshots, don't worry.

Comment: Oh, it must be the proxy here than... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent any of the other images inside the sprite from showing by using [diagonal sprites](http://www.aaronbarker.net/2010/07/diagonal-sprites/), or simply leaving some space between each image.

> I shift the icon (background-position: top/center/bottom)

Use should use explicit `px` offsets instead. I suspect that will be slightly more robust when it comes to zooming.

---

There's nothing you can really do to prevent things sometimes being "1px off" when you zoom.

For example, if you have a `42px` high element, and you zoom to 125%, then you have a `52.5px` high element. The browser must round that number one way or the other.

Comment: i would not recommend that. It bloats sprite your image up. Leaving a little more space between the sprites is ok to

Comment: @meo: Yeah, you're right. Making them diagonal is overkill here.

Comment: Last question - what if my image has height equal to wrapping element? Like arrow on the right side of some menu link? Than padding or leaving more space dont work for me, specially on iPad...

Comment: @Gatekeeper: If you can't predict how much space you have to leave because the element could wrap to any number of lines and then it could show other images in the sprite: try the [diagonal sprites](http://www.aaronbarker.net/2010/07/diagonal-sprites/) link in my answer.

Comment: I think you dont understand.. i have 20px height on div and need to set background icon which has 20px height too... when i leave white spaces between icons than on some zoom levels my div looks thinner in the area of icon because the white space becomes visible. If I put 1px padding in the color of icon on my image, then on other zoom levels my div becomes taller by that one pixel which looks aslo ugly on white background :-/

Comment: @Gatekeeper: Your sprite image should be a `.png` with a fully transparent background, instead of having a solid white background.

Answer (score 1):

Since those images are bitmaps, they always gonna look bad wen you zoom them.

You can do tree things:

1. Use a library like raphael JS and inlude your icons as vectors: http://raphaeljs.com/
2. Wrap your icons into spans for example and using a PX size and not EM's.
3. Leave more speace between your sprites

Answer (score 0):

Try to make better resolution image and try it again.

Comment: I have only ONE background image... it should be clear with those screenshots that i was not able to post here :-(

Answer (score 0):

It's better practice (and ultimately gives you much better control) to use pixel positioning rather than top/center/bottom when implementing CSS sprites, that way the image you want to show can be slightly larger (or with a little spacing) and therefore support that visual overflow you're seeing when you zoom. Your other images/states won't be affected by the neighbouring image/state because you're setting their position with a pixel-specific location rather than top/center/bottom e.g. (from article link below)

```
#panel-a {
    background: transparent url(sprite.jpg) 0 -200px no-repeat;
}
#panel-b {
    background: transparent url(sprite.jpg) -96px -200px no-repeat;
}
#panel-c {
    background: transparent url(sprite.jpg) -172px -200px no-repeat;
}
#panel-d {
    background: transparent url(sprite.jpg) -283px -200px no-repeat;
}
```

Not to mention that pixel positioning allows you to add additional states to *your* image without affecting other existing states if you add them onto the bottom of your image, for example. Of course that changes when you start adding images horizontally.

Here's a good reference: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites